# Find position of HTML tags in text with javascript, preferrably not using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I have text that contains HTML tags. I would like to find out the starting and ending position of each tag pair. That is text position of opening tag and text position of tag.

Because I know that matching tags with regex is complicated (concerning nested tags, quotation marks, etc..) I would like to use some more reliable method - e.g. DOM functions.

Example of my text:

```
text <tag>text text </tag> text
```

Using my example text, the result should be two numbers - 5 (position of opening tag) and 26 (position of last letter of closing tag)

Complicated example of my text:

```
text <tag> text <tag2> text </tag2> text </tag> text
```

In the second example, result should be two numbers - 5 and 47 (position of ending of first level tag - I don't care about nested tags)

Is this possible ? Looking forward to any hints and help. Thank you.

Comment: What is your usecase? This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Writing a function for that in pure javascript (without regex) would take a fair bit of coding, and I'm not aware of any DOM function for that. About regex, [you can read about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1331430).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not answering the question with regards to positions, you might want to look at XMLDom. You'll have to artificially create a root node for the document but things should work:

```
var txt = "text <tag> text <tag2> text </tag2> text </tag> text";
txt = '<root>' + txt + '</root>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");

alert(xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes);
```